# How to compute basic statistics of the time series $Y_j = A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j$

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, expectation, variance, time-series

Given the time series:

$$Y_j = A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j$$

where

- A random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1.$
- Z white noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
- $\theta \in \left\{0, \pi \right\}$ fixed constant
- with $A$ and $Z$ uncorrelated

I would like to compute its **expected value**, **variance** and **auto-covariance function**, and eventually say if it is a stationary process.
I am stuck with the algebra because I lack some basics in probability and statistics.

Here is what I can do:

1. Expected value

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y_j] = \mathbb{E}[A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j] = \mathbb{E}[A \sin(\theta \times j)] + \mathbb{E}[Z_j] = \mathbb{E}[A \sin(\theta \times j)] = \dots?\dots $$

2. Variance

$$ \mathbb{V}(Y_j) = \mathbb{V}(A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j) = \mathbb{V}(A \sin(\theta \times j)) + \mathbb{V}(Z_j) =  \mathbb{V}(A \sin(\theta \times j)) + \sigma^2 = \dots ? \dots $$

3. Auto-covariance

$$ \mathbb{C}(Y_j, Y_{j+l}) = \mathbb{C}(A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j, A \sin(\theta \times (j+l)) + Z_{j+l}) = \\ = \mathbb{C}(A \sin(\theta \times j) + Z_j, A \sin(\theta \times j + \theta \times l)) + Z_{j+l}) = \dots ? \dots $$

Could you explain the steps to do to solve 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic notions: Let $X$ be a r.v. with $\mathbb{E} X = \mu$ and $\operatorname{var}(X) = \sigma ^ 2$. Take scalars $a$ and $b$, hence $\mathbb{E} (aX + b) = a\mu + b$ and $\operatorname{var}(aX + b) = a ^ 2 \sigma ^2 $ and $\operatorname{cov}(aX + b, Y) = a \operatorname{cov}(X, Y)$, therefore

1. $ \mathbb{E}[Y_i] = \sin \theta i \times\mathbb{E} A + 0 = 0.$
2. $ \operatorname{var}[Y_i] = \sin ^ 2 \theta i \times 1 + \sigma ^ 2 = \sigma ^ 2 + \sin ^ 2\theta i.$
3. \begin{align}
   cov(Y_i, Y_j) &=  cov(A \sin \theta i + z_{j}, A \sin \theta j + z_j)\\
   & = cov(A\sin \theta i , A\sin \theta j) + cov(A\sin \theta i , z_i) + cov(A\sin \theta j , z_i) + cov(z_i , z_j)\\
   &=\sin\theta i \sin \theta j\times1 + 0 + 0 + \sigma ^ 2\\
   &=\sin\theta i \sin \theta j + \sigma ^ 2 .
   \end{align}

Comment: it should be $\sin(\theta \times i)$ not $\sin(\theta_i)$

Comment: It does not matter (I edited the answer)

Comment: Ok, 1) and 2) are correct. I thought that $\sin(\theta \times i)$ was not constant because of the $i$, but that's not the case, isn't it?
But 3) is wrong. I need to compute $Cov(Y_i, Y_{i+l}$. Anyway thanks to your answer I could compute it and it is $Cov(Y_i, Y_{i+l}) = \sin(\theta \times j) \times \sin(\theta \times (j+l)) + \sigma^2$. Do you agree?

Comment: 3. Yes, sure. Corrected. 4. Regrading $i+1$ - just plug it in instead of $j$, it doesn't matter. (BTW, you can upvote/accept if it helps you)

Comment: Sure, I will accept in a moment. Finally,can I say that the series is not stationary because the variance is not constant, since it depends on $i$ ?

Comment: It seems to depend on the exact values of $i$ and $j$ and not only on the difference $l$, $j-i = l$, hence not stationary